# Create Websphere deployment descriptior with ANT

Tags: ant, build, websphere, xdoclet

I have created an EAR file for deployment in JBoss application server with ANT 1.8. Now I have a task to create the EAR file to be deployed in Websphere server. When I deployed the previously created ear file, it failed...when I investigated, I found that websphere default deployment descriptor: ibm-web-bnd.xml, ibm-web-ext.xml are not available in my EAR.

I would like to know, If someone do not have RAD/WSAD tools, how can they generate the EAR file compatible for Websphere 7 AS?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Rational Application Developer for Websphere Software build utility. The build utility is an optional, stand-alone utility and is separately installed. Take a look at the following: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/c_install_build_utility_readme.html